# Problem with django's wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

Trying to run on production.

wsgi:

```
import sys                                                                                                                                                                 
import os                                                                                                                                                                  
import os.path                                                                                                                                                             

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))                                                                                                                                 
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'                                                                                                                          

import django.core.handlers.wsgi                                                                                                                                           
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

In apache logs all fine. But in browser:

This webpage is not available
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

Apache/2.2.3 python 2.6.6 mod_wsgi 3.3
modwsgi works on test app.

Comment: Can you post your apache config?

Comment: Definitely something to do with your Apache config. If it was a Python exception, it should have gracefully bubbled through mod_wsgi.

Comment: I find that problem at 'import threading' in django.core.handlers.wsgi
But in python console everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Before running modwsgi on your production code, test the "Hello World" program https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide. If it is running fine, there is an issue with your apache config. Else, the issue lies with modwsgi or wsgi config file.

Comment: And if you add the line 'importing threading' into the WSGI hello world script file what error do you get in the Apache error logs?

Comment: It's a chrome browser error message. Did you check out the site on other browsers? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton - No @Rahul Arora yeah. just not found